# WSL2 > Errors installing GPU driver

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, amdgpu, ubuntu-drivers

Install errors when attempting to run **amdgpu-install -y**, following the below linked guide. Everything else runs well. Suggestions?

Edit: I have made some progress, though still have some errors.

Edit 2: I have python3 installled w/ an alias as python.

Host: Windows 11 Pro 23H2

Guide:

https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-script.html

Ubuntu x86 64-bit driver:

https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers

Drivers installed:

```
scott@PC1:~$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for scott:
  *-display:0
       description: 3D controller
       product: Microsoft Corporation
       vendor: Microsoft Corporation
       physical id: 7
       bus info: pci@5a5b:00:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=dxgkrnl latency=0
       resources: irq:0
  *-display:1
       description: 3D controller
       product: Microsoft Corporation
       vendor: Microsoft Corporation
       physical id: c
       bus info: pci@db05:00:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=dxgkrnl latency=0
       resources: irq:0
```

Install Error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rocm-llvm : Depends: python but it is not installable
             Depends: libstdc++-5-dev but it is not installable or
                      libstdc++-7-dev but it is not installable
             Depends: libgcc-5-dev but it is not installable or
                      libgcc-7-dev but it is not installable
             Recommends: gcc-multilib but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: g++-multilib but it is not going to be installed
 xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu : Depends: xorg-video-abi-24 but it is not installable
```